# Calculate sum of element in array

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn Javascript and have a question about finding the sum of an array. The threads require like this:

****"Define an empty array. Also create two functions:
1/  addNumber() reads a value from a text input field on the HTML document (id="num") and adds it at the end of the array.
2/  printInfo() outputs the amount of elements in the array to the console, then the average of their values.
The HTML document has two buttons for calling the functions. "****

I was able to make it to the part where I can find the total element in the array, but when I try to calculate the sum of this array, using **reduce()** method. But somehow the result shows as a **string** of each element being joint together, but not as a final number. The sum of this array should be the sum of **2 + 7 + 10 + 12 + 25 = 56**

```
var myArray = [];
function addNumber(){
    var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    myArray.push(num);
}

function printInfo(){
    var arr=myArray;
    var array=myArray.length;
    var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;}, 0);
    console.log(sum);
    console.log("The array has " + array + " elements.");
    console.log("The average of the values is " );
}
```

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsAvq.png)

Comment: You are not printing `sum` here: `console.log("The average of the values is " );`. Use `console.log("The average of the values is " +sum);`

Comment: @Martin - Hi, thanks for the solution, but I mean the sum I currently working on is being stringnify from the "document.getElementById("num").value ". So the result would just be 027102512, instead of 56 in total. That's where I stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of input elements are always strings. However, you can change them into numbers with parseInt().

```
myArray.push(parseInt(num));
```

Comment: They are always strings whether it's `type="number"` or not

Comment: @adiga - true, thanks.

Comment: @JohnTyner - Thanks John, I just fix my code following your solution, it's now working perfectly fine now. The course I am participating in, they do not mention anything about using "parseInt()" to convert DOM element to number in the theory. I guess I will have to read more documentation. Thank you. :))

Comment: @nsuspect - another way to convert to a number is to place a plus sign right before it - as in `myArray.push(+num)`

Comment: @JohnTyner - Cool, interesting method, I'll give it try now, thanks again :))